# Using c# and razor in standalone pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, iis-8.5

I've been using razor and c# in MVC and command line applications so far, but it would also be very useful if I could use in a stand alone webpage, for small one-off code snippets and such, in the same way you'd use classic ASP or PHP, where it'd just be too bulky to make a whole project and compile an application.

I tried making just a .cshtml page and putting in some simple razor code there to loop through some dates, but IIS wouldn't process it. Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for? Perhaps this is more of a server question than programming question, if so I apologize in advance.

Comment: did i understand wrong?You want to make webpage just using razor?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible to use it in a manner like PHP or classic asp. Or even just c# itself

Comment: I figured, but I didn't want to quit without asking. Kept hoping maybe there was some way or hack

Comment: take look at asp.net wep pages it is similar to classic asp and php

Comment: @ConvertToInt32 that is being phased out in the next release of ASP.NET, so don't use it any more.

Comment: So what solution would you recommend if one needs something simple and flexible, PHP seems to be the only answer that I can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, unless I am missing something?

Just adding the following `web.config` to my site (IIS 8 on Windows 8.1 Pro) meant that `.cshtml` files worked exactly like classic ASP / PHP; i.e. the URL for them was the filesystem path, and the Razor code ran fine.

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
    <add key="webPages:Version" value="2.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/><!-- I assume that for little test pages you want easy error reporting! -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I'm embarrassed to admit I don't know why it works. The config key suggests it's using ASP.NET Web Pages, which Patrick Hofman says in a comment is being phased out; but I'm pretty sure I've never installed Web Matrix, and all of this was done with Notepad; the IIS site folder simply contains the above minimal `web.config`, a couple of test `.cshtml` files and a single test subfolder to see if the `.cshtml` would be run from there.

What I have done before for simple knocked up test/utility sites is something like the above technique for the UI, but `.cs` files for the program logic put in the `App_Code` folder so .NET wil compile them on the fly.

Example of latter, for anyone who's not played with `/App_Code` before:

1) Create an `/App_Code` folder

2) Add perfectly normal `.cs` file to it with your class definitions:

```
using System;

namespace Minimal
{
    public class Boo
    {
        public static String Get()
        {
            return "BOO!";
        }
    }
}
```

3) That is magically compiled and available as code in any normal assembly would be.

4) So you can create a view like:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>@Minimal.Boo.Get()</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's very handy; makes even quickly knocked up tools and tests clear and easy to develop, and also very easy to add to a normal VS project if they become mature enough for that.

Comment: You are totally right. Thanks for enlightening me today.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I hope my many many edits didn't confuse the issue, I should have done a bit more playing around before I actually posted :)

Comment: No problem. The reason it works is that calling cshtml is handled by the ASP.NET ISAPI handler, not ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: No problem, I actually didn't know it was quite this simple myself until I just started playing around with it today :)